# Question Regarding Calculating Percentage of Mean of a Group Where the Mean is >= 4 using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

So I've this survey response data, where the survey has different sections, and each section has several sub-questions, and user will vote for each question. Note: there are not only one brand, but in this sample data, I'm only showing one.

```
Brand   Section Question    Vote
Apple   S01     S01Q1       3
Apple   S01     S01Q2       4
Apple   S01     S01Q3       5
Apple   S01     S01Q4       3
Apple   S02     S02Q1       4
Apple   S02     S02Q2       5
Apple   S02     S02Q3       4
Apple   S01     S01Q1       4
Apple   S01     S01Q2       2
Apple   S01     S01Q3       3
Apple   S01     S01Q4       5
Apple   S02     S02Q1       4
Apple   S02     S02Q2       3
Apple   S02     S02Q3       4
```

For the dataset, I'll be calculating the mean for each question. Say for question `S01Q1`, the calculation will be `(3 + 4) / 2 = 3.5`, refer to below.

```
Brand   Section Question    Mean
Apple   S01     S01Q1       3.5
Apple   S01     S01Q2       3
Apple   S01     S01Q3       4
Apple   S01     S01Q4       4
Apple   S02     S02Q1       4
Apple   S02     S02Q2       4
Apple   S02     S02Q3       4
```

And after that, I would like to calculate the percentage of mean where the mean is more than or equal to 4 for each section, refer below, How can I achieve this using measure, and without creating extra tables, only using the first dataset?

```
Brand   Section % of Mean >= 4
Apple   S01     50%
Apple   S02     100%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following **measure**:

```
=
VAR T1 =
    SUMMARIZE(
        Table1,
        Table1[Question],
        "Mean", AVERAGE( Table1[Vote] )
    )
RETURN
    DIVIDE(
        SUMX(
            T1,
            0 + ( [Mean] >= 4 )
        ),
        COUNTROWS( T1 )
    )
```